# how to send data message to user segment From Rest API

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, advanced-rest-client

I'm using Advanced REST API to send data message for push notification. 
In firebase console i can select user segment 
as "Version","language",Country" etc..But how to select user segment for 
Data message sent from REST API? 
Or is their any other way to use select User segment for data message? 
Also i want to send the notification for the user who has not opened app for few days.Is it possible with firebase data message?

Answer (score 1):

When using the FCM rest API to send message, you can't target Analytics user segments.  You can only send to devices identified by their unique token, or to topics where the client app is subscribed.  The only way to send a message to a user segment is through the Firebase console.